# UPDATE with JOIN: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RIGHT'

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, update

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2005. I want to look up a column value in another table, using a shared ID `tblOrder_ordernr` in both tables, but only update one table.

To me, the query is strangely written (`UPDATE tblTid` but `SET viewOrderAlla...`), but this is what I have to work with. How would I rewrite this query to do the same?

```
UPDATE tblTid RIGHT JOIN viewOrderAlla ON tblTid.sOrdernr = viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_ordernr 
SET viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_verkligtid = 0
WHERE viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_verkligtid<>0 AND tblTid.iTidID Is Null 
AND viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_levdatum>=DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE())
```

I've tried moving the SET to before the RIGHT JOIN as per some other questions here, but I find no answer that even lets me parse the expression without a syntax error.

The tables are linked into an Access 2013 database, and there, the query runs fine. But not in SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE viewOrderAlla
SET viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_verkligtid = 0
FROM tblTid
RIGHT JOIN viewOrderAlla ON tblTid.sOrdernr = viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_ordernr
WHERE viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_verkligtid <> 0
    AND tblTid.iTidID IS NULL
    AND viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_levdatum >= DATEADD(month, - 6, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with writing SELECT Statements, using a CTE to separate the SELECT from the UPDATE can make it easier to get your head around what the query is doing.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        iewOrderAlla.tblOrder_verkligtid AS [OldValue]
        ,0 AS [NewValue]
    FROM tblTid
    RIGHT JOIN viewOrderAlla ON tblTid.sOrdernr = viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_ordernr
    WHERE viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_verkligtid <> 0
        AND tblTid.iTidID IS NULL
        AND viewOrderAlla.tblOrder_levdatum >= DATEADD(month, - 6, GETDATE())
)
UPDATE cte
SET [OldValue] = [NewValue]
```